# Spark application kills executor

Tags: apache-spark

I'm running spark cluster in standalone mode and application using spark-submit. In spark UI stage section I found executing stage with large execution time ( > 10h, when usual time ~30 sec). Stage have many failed tasks with error `Resubmitted (resubmitted due to lost executor)`. There is executor with address `CANNOT FIND ADDRESS` in `Aggregated Metrics by Executor` section in the stage page. Spark tries to resubmit this task infinitely. If I kill this stage (my application rerun uncompleted spark jobs automatically) all continue working good.

Also I found some strange entries in spark logs (same time as stage execution start).

Master:

```
16/11/19 19:04:32 INFO Master: Application app-20161109161724-0045 requests to kill executors: 0
16/11/19 19:04:36 INFO Master: Launching executor app-20161109161724-0045/1 on worker worker-20161108150133
16/11/19 19:05:03 WARN Master: Got status update for unknown executor app-20161109161724-0045/0
16/11/25 10:05:46 INFO Master: Application app-20161109161724-0045 requests to kill executors: 1
16/11/25 10:05:48 INFO Master: Launching executor app-20161109161724-0045/2 on worker worker-20161108150133
16/11/25 10:06:14 WARN Master: Got status update for unknown executor app-20161109161724-0045/1
```

Worker:

```
16/11/25 10:06:05 INFO Worker: Asked to kill executor app-20161109161724-0045/1
16/11/25 10:06:08 INFO ExecutorRunner: Runner thread for executor app-20161109161724-0045/1 interrupted
16/11/25 10:06:08 INFO ExecutorRunner: Killing process!
16/11/25 10:06:13 INFO Worker: Executor app-20161109161724-0045/1 finished with state KILLED exitStatus 137
16/11/25 10:06:14 INFO Worker: Asked to launch executor app-20161109161724-0045/2 for app.jar
16/11/25 10:06:17 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: spark
16/11/25 10:06:17 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: spark
16/11/25 10:06:17 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(spark); users with modify permissions: Set(spark)
```

There is no problem with network connections because worker, master (logs above), driver running on the same machine.

Spark version 1.6.1

Comment: Can you add the logs of the worker causing the trouble? A worker can be killed in case a task fails number of times. Are there any exceptions happening?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov worker logs in pos - logs from worker with lost executor. There are no exceptions and fails before executor was lost.

Comment: *"worker logs in pos - logs from worker with lost executor"* Not sure what that means

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov sorry, "worker logs in post (my question)". I added worker logs in my questions. This worker lost executor.

Comment: @Cortwave which of the suggestions in the accepted answer worked for you?

Comment: @vefthym more memory allocation helped

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Likely the interesting part of the log is this:

```
16/11/25 10:06:13 INFO Worker: Executor app-20161109161724-0045/1 finished with state KILLED exitStatus 137
```

Exit `137` strongly suggest a resource issue, either memory or cpu cores.
Given that you can fix your issues by rerunning the stage it could be that somehow all cores are already allocated (maybe you also have some Spark shell running?).
This is a common issue with standalone Spark setups (everything on one host).

Either way I would try the following things in order:

1. Raise the storage memory faction `spark.storage.memoryFraction` to pre-allocate more memory for storage and prevent the system OOM killer to randomly give you that `137` on a big stage.
2. Set a lower number of cores for your application to rule out something pre-allocating those cores before your stage is ran. You can do this via `spark.deploy.defaultCores`, set it to 3 or even 2 (on an intel quad-core assuming 8 vcores)
3. Outright allocate more RAM to Spark -> `spark.executor.memory` needs to go up.
4. Maybe you run into an issue with meta data cleanup here, also not unheard of in local deployments, in this case adding
   `export SPARK_JAVA_OPTS +="-Dspark.kryoserializer.buffer.mb=10 -Dspark.cleaner.ttl=43200"` to the end your `spark-env.sh` might do the trick by forcing the meta data cleanup to run more frequently

One of these should do the trick in my opinion.

Comment: Hi Armin, Do you know what is the equivalent of spark.storage.memoryFraction in spark 2.3.x onwards? This parameter is deprecated.

Comment: There is spark.memory.storageFraction now but the effect is not 1:1 comparable to the legacy setting.

Answer (score 4):

Armin's answer is very good. I just wanted to point to what worked for me.

The same problem went away when I increased the parameter:

`spark.default.parallelism` from 28 (which was the number of executors that I had) to 84 (which is the number of available cores).

**NOTE:** this is not a rule for setting this parameter, this is only what worked for me.

**UPDATE**: This approach is also backed by [Spark's documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html):

> Sometimes, you will get an OutOfMemoryError not because your RDDs don’t fit in memory, but because the working set of one of your tasks, such as one of the reduce tasks in groupByKey, was too large. Spark’s shuffle operations (sortByKey, groupByKey, reduceByKey, join, etc) build a hash table within each task to perform the grouping, which can often be large. **The simplest fix here is to increase the level of parallelism, so that each task’s input set is smaller.** Spark can efficiently support tasks as short as 200 ms, because it reuses one executor JVM across many tasks and it has a low task launching cost, so you can safely increase the level of parallelism to more than the number of cores in your clusters.

Comment: Do you have some theoretical explanation for this?

Comment: @Cortwave yes, increasing the number of partition reduces the memory requirements of each task (each partition is handled by one task). As for the specific number, no, but in my previous MapReduce experience, adding more partitions had the same behavior and I kept increasing them until no OOM errors were thrown (when applicable).