# Spark Standalone Mode, application runs, but executor is killed with exitStatus 1

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-standalone

I am new to Apache Spark and was trying to run the example Pi Calculation application on my local spark setup (using Standalone Cluster).
Both the Master, Slave and Driver are running on my local machine.

What I am noticing is that, the PI is calculated successfully, however in the slave logs I see that the Worker/Executor is being killed with exitStatus 1.
I do not see any errors/exceptions logged to the console otherwise.
I tried finding help on similar issue, but most of the search hits were referring to exitStatus 137 etc. (e.g: [Spark application kills executor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40910952/spark-application-kills-executor))

I have failed miserably to understand why the Worker is being killed instead of completing the execution with '`EXITED`' state. I think it's related to how I am executing the app, but am not quite clear what am I doing wrong.
Can someone guide me on identifying the root cause?

Given below is the  code I am using for PI calculation and the logs of the master, slave, driver respsectively.

**PI Calculation Application**

```
package sparky

import org.apache.spark.scheduler._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

import scala.math.random

object Application {
  def runSpark(args: Array[String] ): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder
      .appName("Spark Pi")
      .getOrCreate()

    spark.sparkContext.addSparkListener(new MyListener())

    val slices = if (args.length > 0) args(0).toInt else 2
    val n = math.min(100000L * slices, Int.MaxValue).toInt // avoid overflow
    val count = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(1 until n, slices).map { i =>
      val x = random * 2 - 1
      val y = random * 2 - 1
      if (x * x + y * y <= 1) 1 else 0
    }.reduce(_ + _)
    println("Pi is roughly " + 4.0 * count / (n - 1))
    spark.stop()
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    Application.runSpark(args)
  }
}
```

**Master Console Output**

```
C:\Servers\apache-spark\2.2.0\bin
λ start-master.cmd -h 0.0.0.0
C:\Platforms\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin\java -cp "C:\Servers\apache-spark\2.2.0\bin\..\conf\;C:\Servers\apache-spark\2.2.0\bin\..\jars\*" -Xmx1g org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master
18/01/25 09:01:30,099 INFO Master: Started daemon with process name: 14900@somemachine
18/01/25 09:01:30,580 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
18/01/25 09:01:30,680 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: someuser
18/01/25 09:01:30,681 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: someuser
18/01/25 09:01:30,682 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to:
18/01/25 09:01:30,683 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to:
18/01/25 09:01:30,684 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(someuser); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(someuser); groups with modify permissions: Set()
18/01/25 09:01:31,711 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkMaster' on port 7077.
18/01/25 09:01:31,829 INFO Master: Starting Spark master at spark://0.0.0.0:7077
18/01/25 09:01:31,833 INFO Master: Running Spark version 2.2.0
18/01/25 09:01:31,903 INFO log: Logging initialized @2692ms
18/01/25 09:01:31,960 INFO Server: jetty-9.3.z-SNAPSHOT
18/01/25 09:01:32,025 INFO Server: Started @2816ms
18/01/25 09:01:32,057 INFO AbstractConnector: Started ServerConnector@106ca013{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080}
18/01/25 09:01:32,058 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'MasterUI' on port 8080.
18/01/25 09:01:32,087 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@41cc88b{/app,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/01/25 09:01:32,088 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@1c63bda6{/app/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/01/25 09:01:32,089 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@45ae273f{/,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/01/25 09:01:32,090 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@7a319c60{/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/01/25 09:01:32,098 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@23510beb{/static,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}

18/01/25 09:01:32,099 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@462c632c{/app/kill,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/01/25 09:01:32,101 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@436ef27b{/driver/kill,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/01/25 09:01:32,104 INFO MasterWebUI: Bound MasterWebUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://192.168.56.1:8080
18/01/25 09:01:32,119 INFO Server: jetty-9.3.z-SNAPSHOT
18/01/25 09:01:32,130 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@6f7d1cba{/,null,AVAILABLE}
18/01/25 09:01:32,134 INFO AbstractConnector: Started ServerConnector@3f9e9637{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:6066}
18/01/25 09:01:32,134 INFO Server: Started @2925ms
18/01/25 09:01:32,134 INFO Utils: Successfully started service on port 6066.
18/01/25 09:01:32,135 INFO StandaloneRestServer: Started REST server for submitting applications on port 6066
18/01/25 09:01:32,358 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@7b3e5adb{/metrics/master/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/01/25 09:01:32,362 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@139cbe00{/metrics/applications/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/01/25 09:01:32,399 INFO Master: I have been elected leader! New state: ALIVE
18/01/25 09:01:41,225 INFO Master: Registering worker 192.168.56.1:48591 with 4 cores, 14.4 GB RAM
18/01/25 09:01:53,510 INFO Master: Registering app Spark Pi
18/01/25 09:01:53,515 INFO Master: Registered app Spark Pi with ID app-20180125090153-0000
18/01/25 09:01:53,569 INFO Master: Launching executor app-20180125090153-0000/0 on worker worker-20180125090140-192.168.56.1-48591
18/01/25 09:02:00,262 INFO Master: Received unregister request from application app-20180125090153-0000
18/01/25 09:02:00,269 INFO Master: Removing app app-20180125090153-0000
18/01/25 09:02:00,323 WARN Master: Got status update for unknown executor app-20180125090153-0000/0
18/01/25 09:02:00,338 INFO Master: 127.0.0.1:48625 got disassociated, removing it.
18/01/25 09:02:00,345 INFO Master: 192.168.56.1:48620 got disassociated, removing it.
```

**Slave Console Output**

```
C:\Servers\apache-spark\2.2.0\bin
λ start-slave.cmd -h 0.0.0.0
C:\Platforms\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin\java -cp "C:\Servers\apache-spark\2.2.0\bin\..\conf\;C:\Servers\apache-spark\2.2.0\bin\..\jars\*" -Xmx1g org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://0.0.0.0:7077
18/01/25 09:01:38,054 INFO Worker: Started daemon with process name: 14532@somemachine
18/01/25 09:01:38,546 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
18/01/25 09:01:38,644 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: someuser
18/01/25 09:01:38,645 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: someuser
18/01/25 09:01:38,646 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to:
18/01/25 09:01:38,647 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to:
18/01/25 09:01:38,648 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(someuser); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(someuser); groups with modify permissions: Set()
18/01/25 09:01:39,655 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkWorker' on port 48591.
18/01/25 09:01:40,521 INFO Worker: Starting Spark worker 192.168.56.1:48591 with 4 cores, 14.4 GB RAM
18/01/25 09:01:40,526 INFO Worker: Running Spark version 2.2.0
18/01/25 09:01:40,527 INFO Worker: Spark home: C:\Servers\apache-spark\2.2.0\bin\..
18/01/25 09:01:40,586 INFO log: Logging initialized @3430ms
18/01/25 09:01:40,636 INFO Server: jetty-9.3.z-SNAPSHOT
18/01/25 09:01:40,657 INFO Server: Started @3503ms
18/01/25 09:01:40,787 WARN Utils: Service 'WorkerUI' could not bind on port 8081. Attempting port 8082.
18/01/25 09:01:40,797 INFO AbstractConnector: Started ServerConnector@24c54ec4{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8082}
18/01/25 09:01:40,797 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'WorkerUI' on port 8082.
18/01/25 09:01:40,832 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@6e86345{/logPage,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}

18/01/25 09:01:40,833 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@43dbfd42{/logPage/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/01/25 09:01:40,834 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@768b7729{/,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/01/25 09:01:40,836 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@382e7183{/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/01/25 09:01:40,844 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@459d7b70{/static,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}

18/01/25 09:01:40,845 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@5bf4fc9c{/log,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/01/25 09:01:40,849 INFO WorkerWebUI: Bound WorkerWebUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://192.168.56.1:8082
18/01/25 09:01:40,853 INFO Worker: Connecting to master 0.0.0.0:7077...
18/01/25 09:01:40,885 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@4e93ba9d{/metrics/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/01/25 09:01:40,971 INFO TransportClientFactory: Successfully created connection to /0.0.0.0:7077 after 82 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
18/01/25 09:01:41,246 INFO Worker: Successfully registered with master spark://0.0.0.0:7077
18/01/25 09:01:53,621 INFO Worker: Asked to launch executor app-20180125090153-0000/0 for Spark Pi
18/01/25 09:01:53,661 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: someuser
18/01/25 09:01:53,663 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: someuser
18/01/25 09:01:53,664 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to:
18/01/25 09:01:53,668 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to:
18/01/25 09:01:53,669 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(someuser); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(someuser); groups with modify permissions: Set()
18/01/25 09:01:53,695 INFO ExecutorRunner: Launch command: "C:\Platforms\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin\java" "-cp" "C:\Servers\apache-spark\2.2.0\bin\..\conf\;C:\Servers\apache-spark\2.2.0\bin\..\jars\*" "-Xmx1024M" "-Dspark.driver.port=48620" "org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend" "--driver-url" "spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@192.168.56.1:48620" "--executor-id" "0" "--hostname" "192.168.56.1" "--cores" "4" "--app-id" "app-20180125090153-0000" "--worker-url" "spark://Worker@192.168.56.1:48591"
18/01/25 09:02:00,297 INFO Worker: Asked to kill executor app-20180125090153-0000/0
18/01/25 09:02:00,303 INFO ExecutorRunner: Runner thread for executor app-20180125090153-0000/0 interrupted
18/01/25 09:02:00,305 INFO ExecutorRunner: Killing process!
18/01/25 09:02:00,323 INFO Worker: Executor app-20180125090153-0000/0 finished with state KILLED exitStatus 1
18/01/25 09:02:00,336 INFO ExternalShuffleBlockResolver: Application app-20180125090153-0000 removed, cleanupLocalDirs = true
18/01/25 09:02:00,340 INFO Worker: Cleaning up local directories for application app-20180125090153-0000
```

**Driver Console Output**

```
9:01:47 AM: Executing task 'submitToSpark'...

C:\Applications\scala\sparky\app\build\libs\sparky-app-0.0.1.jar
:app:compileJava NO-SOURCE
:app:compileScala UP-TO-DATE
:app:processResources NO-SOURCE
:app:classes UP-TO-DATE
:app:jar UP-TO-DATE
:runner:submitToSpark
C:\Platforms\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin\java -cp "C:\Servers\apache-spark\2.2.0\bin\..\conf\;C:\Servers\apache-spark\2.2.0\bin\..\jars\*" -Xmx1g org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit --master spark://localhost:7077 C:\Applications\scala\sparky\app\build\libs\sparky-app-0.0.1.jar 
18/01/25 09:01:51,111 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 2.2.0
18/01/25 09:01:51,465 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
18/01/25 09:01:51,677 INFO SparkContext: Submitted application: Spark Pi
18/01/25 09:01:51,711 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: someuser
18/01/25 09:01:51,712 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: someuser
18/01/25 09:01:51,712 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
18/01/25 09:01:51,713 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
18/01/25 09:01:51,714 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(someuser); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(someuser); groups with modify permissions: Set()
18/01/25 09:01:52,639 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 48620.
18/01/25 09:01:52,669 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
18/01/25 09:01:52,695 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
18/01/25 09:01:52,699 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Using org.apache.spark.storage.DefaultTopologyMapper for getting topology information
18/01/25 09:01:52,700 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: BlockManagerMasterEndpoint up
18/01/25 09:01:52,712 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at C:\Users\someuser\AppData\Local\Temp\blockmgr-f9908c61-a91a-43d5-8d24-e0fd86d55d1c
18/01/25 09:01:52,740 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 366.3 MB
18/01/25 09:01:52,808 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
18/01/25 09:01:52,924 INFO log: Logging initialized @3539ms
18/01/25 09:01:53,009 INFO Server: jetty-9.3.z-SNAPSHOT
18/01/25 09:01:53,038 INFO Server: Started @3654ms
18/01/25 09:01:53,067 INFO AbstractConnector: Started ServerConnector@21a5fd96{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:4040}
18/01/25 09:01:53,067 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
18/01/25 09:01:53,099 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@40bffbca{/jobs,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/01/25 09:01:53,100 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@6c4f9535{/jobs/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/01/25 09:01:53,100 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@30c31dd7{/jobs/job,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/01/25 09:01:53,101 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@c1fca1e{/jobs/job/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/01/25 09:01:53,102 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@344344fa{/stages,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/01/25 09:01:53,103 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@70e659aa{/stages/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/01/25 09:01:53,103 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@285f09de{/stages/stage,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/01/25 09:01:53,105 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@48e64352{/stages/stage/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/01/25 09:01:53,106 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@4362d7df{/stages/pool,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/01/25 09:01:53,106 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@1c25b8a7{/stages/pool/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/01/25 09:01:53,107 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@750fe12e{/storage,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/01/25 09:01:53,108 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@3e587920{/storage/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/01/25 09:01:53,108 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@24f43aa3{/storage/rdd,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/01/25 09:01:53,109 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@1e11bc55{/storage/rdd/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/01/25 09:01:53,110 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@70e0accd{/environment,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/01/25 09:01:53,112 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@6ab72419{/environment/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/01/25 09:01:53,112 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@4fdfa676{/executors,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/01/25 09:01:53,113 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@5be82d43{/executors/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/01/25 09:01:53,114 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@345e5a17{/executors/threadDump,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/01/25 09:01:53,115 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@443dbe42{/executors/threadDump/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/01/25 09:01:53,125 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@1734f68{/static,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/01/25 09:01:53,125 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@31c269fd{/,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/01/25 09:01:53,127 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@47747fb9{/api,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/01/25 09:01:53,128 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@70eecdc2{/jobs/job/kill,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/01/25 09:01:53,129 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@7db0565c{/stages/stage/kill,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/01/25 09:01:53,133 INFO SparkUI: Bound SparkUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://192.168.56.1:4040
18/01/25 09:01:53,174 INFO SparkContext: Added JAR file:/C:/Applications/scala/sparky/app/build/libs/sparky-app-0.0.1.jar at spark://192.168.56.1:48620/jars/sparky-app-0.0.1.jar with timestamp 1516888913174
18/01/25 09:01:53,318 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Connecting to master spark://localhost:7077...
18/01/25 09:01:53,389 INFO TransportClientFactory: Successfully created connection to localhost/127.0.0.1:7077 after 42 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
18/01/25 09:01:53,554 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Connected to Spark cluster with app ID app-20180125090153-0000
18/01/25 09:01:53,577 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 48642.
18/01/25 09:01:53,578 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 192.168.56.1:48642
18/01/25 09:01:53,582 INFO BlockManager: Using org.apache.spark.storage.RandomBlockReplicationPolicy for block replication policy
18/01/25 09:01:53,590 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registering BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.56.1, 48642, None)
18/01/25 09:01:53,595 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 192.168.56.1:48642 with 366.3 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.56.1, 48642, None)
18/01/25 09:01:53,600 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.56.1, 48642, None)
18/01/25 09:01:53,601 INFO BlockManager: Initialized BlockManager: BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.56.1, 48642, None)
18/01/25 09:01:53,667 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor added: app-20180125090153-0000/0 on worker-20180125090140-192.168.56.1-48591 (192.168.56.1:48591) with 4 cores
18/01/25 09:01:53,668 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20180125090153-0000/0 on hostPort 192.168.56.1:48591 with 4 cores, 1024.0 MB RAM
18/01/25 09:01:53,901 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@74fef3f7{/metrics/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/01/25 09:01:55,026 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20180125090153-0000/0 is now RUNNING
18/01/25 09:01:55,096 INFO EventLoggingListener: Logging events to file:///C:/Dustbin/spark-events/app-20180125090153-0000
18/01/25 09:01:55,127 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: SchedulerBackend is ready for scheduling beginning after reached minRegisteredResourcesRatio: 0.0
18/01/25 09:01:55,218 INFO SharedState: Setting hive.metastore.warehouse.dir ('null') to the value of spark.sql.warehouse.dir ('file:/C:/Applications/scala/sparky/runner/spark-warehouse/').
18/01/25 09:01:55,219 INFO SharedState: Warehouse path is 'file:/C:/Applications/scala/sparky/runner/spark-warehouse/'.
18/01/25 09:01:55,228 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@50a691d3{/SQL,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/01/25 09:01:55,228 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@3b95d13c{/SQL/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/01/25 09:01:55,229 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@54d901aa{/SQL/execution,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/01/25 09:01:55,230 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@573284a5{/SQL/execution/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/01/25 09:01:55,233 INFO ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@507b79f7{/static/sql,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
18/01/25 09:01:56,232 INFO StateStoreCoordinatorRef: Registered StateStoreCoordinator endpoint
18/01/25 09:01:56,609 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: reduce at Application.scala:29
18/01/25 09:01:56,636 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 0 (reduce at Application.scala:29) with 2 output partitions
18/01/25 09:01:56,637 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 0 (reduce at Application.scala:29)
18/01/25 09:01:56,638 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
18/01/25 09:01:56,640 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
18/01/25 09:01:56,654 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[1] at map at Application.scala:25), which has no missing parents
18/01/25 09:01:56,815 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 1800.0 B, free 366.3 MB)
18/01/25 09:01:56,980 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 1168.0 B, free 366.3 MB)
18/01/25 09:01:56,984 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on 192.168.56.1:48642 (size: 1168.0 B, free: 366.3 MB)
18/01/25 09:01:56,988 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 0 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1006
18/01/25 09:01:57,016 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 2 missing tasks from ResultStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[1] at map at Application.scala:25) (first 15 tasks are for partitions Vector(0, 1))
18/01/25 09:01:57,018 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 0.0 with 2 tasks
18/01/25 09:01:58,617 INFO CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint: Registered executor NettyRpcEndpointRef(spark-client://Executor) (192.168.56.1:48660) with ID 0
18/01/25 09:01:58,661 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, 192.168.56.1, executor 0, partition 0, PROCESS_LOCAL, 4829 bytes)
18/01/25 09:01:58,665 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1, 192.168.56.1, executor 0, partition 1, PROCESS_LOCAL, 4829 bytes)
18/01/25 09:01:59,242 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 192.168.56.1:48678 with 366.3 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(0, 192.168.56.1, 48678, None)
18/01/25 09:01:59,819 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on 192.168.56.1:48678 (size: 1168.0 B, free: 366.3 MB)
18/01/25 09:02:00,139 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) in 1500 ms on 192.168.56.1 (executor 0) (1/2)
18/01/25 09:02:00,142 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1) in 1478 ms on 192.168.56.1 (executor 0) (2/2)
18/01/25 09:02:00,143 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 0.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
18/01/25 09:02:00,150 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 0 (reduce at Application.scala:29) finished in 3.109 s
18/01/25 09:02:00,156 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 0 finished: reduce at Application.scala:29, took 3.546255 s
Pi is roughly 3.1363756818784094
18/01/25 09:02:00,168 INFO AbstractConnector: Stopped Spark@21a5fd96{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:4040}
18/01/25 09:02:00,170 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://192.168.56.1:4040
18/01/25 09:02:00,247 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Shutting down all executors
18/01/25 09:02:00,249 INFO CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint: Asking each executor to shut down
18/01/25 09:02:00,269 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
18/01/25 09:02:00,300 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
18/01/25 09:02:00,301 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
18/01/25 09:02:00,321 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
18/01/25 09:02:00,328 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
18/01/25 09:02:00,353 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
2018-01-25 09:02:00.353
18/01/25 09:02:00,358 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
18/01/25 09:02:00,360 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory C:\Users\someuser\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-ac6369a0-abb8-476e-a527-91e0a8011302

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 13s
3 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 2 up-to-date
9:02:01 AM: Task execution finished 'submitToSpark'.
```

Comment: Experiencing same behavior under Spark 2.3 in Standalone mode for the same application (SparkPi). In my case, executors return with exitStatus 0 and worker reports them as KILLED (??)